# solving ln property equations such as: $\ln\sqrt{b^{−2}c^{−3}a^{1}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Hi I have a homework problem that is always wrong and I dont know which problem I have wrong. Its really annoying since it doesn't indicate which one is wrong, it just says something is incorrect. I have gone through these multiple times and still can't figure it out.

If $\ln a=2$, $\ln b=3$, and $\ln c=5$, evaluate the following:

(a) $$\ln\frac{(a^{3})}{(b^{−3}c^{−4})} = -23$$

(b) $$\ln\sqrt{b^{−2}c^{−3}a^{1}}= -19/2$$

(c) $$\frac{\ln(a^{−1}b^{2})}{ln(bc)^{−1}}= 12$$

(d) $${\ln c^{−2}}{{(\ln\frac{a}{b^{2}}})^{3}}= 640$$

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Answer (score 0):

ln a=2, ln b=3, and ln c=5

$\ln\frac{a^3}{(b^{−3})(c^{−4})} = \ln a^3 - \ln ((b^{−3})(c^{−4})) =  \ln a^3 -(\ln b^{−3} + \ln c^{−4})=  \ln a^3 -\ln b^{−3} - \ln c^{−4} = 3\ln a + 3 \ln b + 4 \ln c = 6 + 9 +20 = 35$
so that one is wrong.

$\ln ((b^{−2})(c^{−3})(a^1))^{1/2} = \frac 12 [-2 \ln b - 3 \ln c + \ln a]= \frac 12 [-6 - 15 + 2] = -19/2$ 
so that one is right.

Comment: Unfortunately the homework overall is still wrong. I tried 35 before. As of right now I have: (a) = 35, (b) = -19/2, (c) = -4, (d) = 640. The homework isn't telling me which one is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exponents on (a). You'll find at least part of your issue there. (c) also appears to be incorrect, but it's not super clear what the equation should be. Should the (-1) exponent in the denominator apply to only the (bc) or to the entire logarithm?

Comment: It is exactly as is shown in the homework. (c) the -1 I am assuming applies to the whole logarithm. So the denominator should look like: $ln{bc}^{-1}$ = $(ln{b} * ln{c})^{-1}$ = 15^(-1). I have tried adding them and eventually (c) comes out to -4, which still doesn't solve the homework.

Comment: $ln(bc) = ln(b) + ln (c)$

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't give the right answer. Even when I add them the answer is still apparently wrong. :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (a) and (b) have been vetted, and I checked (d) which is correct (640).

So let's take a shot at (c):

$$\frac{\ln(a^{−1}b^{2})}{\ln(bc)^{−1}}=\frac{-\ln a+2\ln b}{-(\ln b+\ln c)} =\frac{-2+2(3)}{-(3+5)}=\frac4{-8}= -\frac12$$